# Replacing date in datetime with another date

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime

```
    string t3 = "01:30 AM";
    txtStartDate.text = "12-Mar-2013";
    DateTime dat1 = DateTime.Parse(txtStartDate.Text);
    DateTime dat2 = (DateTime.ParseExact(t3, "H:mm tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
    //this gives 5/30/2013 1:30:00 AM 
    // 5/30/2013 is current date
```

I want to replace current date with dat1 value
that is, I want dat2 to have 12/mar/2013 1:30:00:AM

can anyone help me doing this?
thanks in advance

Comment: Use DatePart to extract the bits you want to keep / the time, then Add to put it back on date2

Comment: check this out: http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/23/Date-Formatting-in-CSharp

Comment: @SandreaDsouza You want to replace system's currentDateTime with dat1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After parsing the data string `dat1` is set to 12:00 midnight, so you can add the `TimeOfDay` from `dat2` to it.

```
    var t3 = "01:30 AM";
    txtStartDate.text = "12-Mar-2013";
    DateTime dat1 = DateTime.Parse(txtStartDate.text);

    DateTime dat2 = (DateTime.ParseExact(t3, "H:mm tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));

    dat1 = dat1.Add(dat2.TimeOfDay); // <-- added this line

    //this gives 3/12/2013 1:30:00 AM 
    Console.WriteLine(dat1);
    Console.WriteLine(dat2);
```

Answer (score 1):

Personally I use something like this:

```
dat2 = new DateTime(dat1.Year, dat1.Month, dat1.Day, dat2.Hour, dat2.Minunte, dat2.Seconds, dat2.Milliseconds);
```

But I had the challenge that the time was set to something.

Answer (score 1):

Simple addition would work.

```
DateTime date = DateTime.Parse(txtStartDate.text) + DateTime.ParseExact(t3, "H:mm tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).TimeOfDay;
```